# mybatis @Select with a static factory of sql keyword get a error when compile?

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors, mybatis

when I use @Select which is a annotation of ibatis with the code:

```
@Select({"SELECT ", selectField, " FROM ", table, "WHERE finished = #{finished}"})
 List<ToDo> listToDoByFinished(@Param("finished") Integer finished);
```

It works right and can compile through,but when I change code to follow:

```
//FIXME
@Select({SELECT, selectField, FROM, table, WHERE, finished, EQUAL, "#{finished}"})
 List<ToDo> listToDoByFinished(@Param("finished") Integer finished);
```

It cannot compile through and error info is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project blog: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/freeze/my_project/lbfreeze-blog/src/main/java/me/freezehome/blog/dao/ToDoDAO.java:[32,54] 错误（error): 不兼容的类型(type mismatch): Integer无法转换为String(Interger cannot convert to String)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

the sql key word defined in the `SqlFactory`:

```
package me.freezehome.blog.factory;

public  class SqlFactory {
    private SqlFactory(){}
    public static final  String SELECT = " SELECT ";
    public static final  String INSERT = " INSERT ";
    public static final  String UPDATE = " UPDATE ";
    public static final  String DELETE = " DELETE ";

    public static final  String WHERE = " WHERE ";
    public static final  String FROM = " FROM ";
    public static final  String AND = " AND ";
    public static final  String OR = " OR ";
    public static final  String IN = " IN ";
    public static final  String INTO = " INTO ";
    public static final  String VALUES = "VALUES";
    public static final  String EQUAL = " = ";


}
```

others defined in the interface:

```
package me.freezehome.blog.dao;

import me.freezehome.blog.driver.MyInLanguageDriver;
import me.freezehome.blog.model.ToDo;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;

import java.util.List;

import static me.freezehome.blog.config.StringConfig.strSeparator;
import static me.freezehome.blog.factory.SqlFactory.*;

public interface ToDoDAO {
    String table = "todo";
    String id = "id";
    String title = "title";
    String content = "content";
    String finished = "finished";

    String selectField = id + strSeparator + title + strSeparator + content + strSeparator + finished;
    String insertField = title + strSeparator + content;
}
```

the others info:

- mybatis 3.4.1
- mybatis-spring 1.3.0
- spring 4.3.3
- mavne 3.3.9
- java  "1.8.0_111"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this code on my small application. As result, the Java compiler will try refer a method argument of same name as constants.

In this case, the Java Compile will try refer the method argument(`finished` defined as `Integer`) instead of `String finished = "finished";`(constant). Therefore type conversion error is occurred on compile time.

I don't know whether it is specification or not on Java Compiler.

Probably you can resolve this issue by converting a constant name to the upper case.

Comment: yes, I resolve it by using upper case, but I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have import static SqlFactory.*

In interface ToDoDAO all String shall be static final as annotations require constant parameters.

Comment: why?The variables  of SqlFactory  are all static final.

Comment: variables of interface ToDoDAO are not but must

Comment: but Why I can not import static SqlFactory.*?

Comment: No, You have to `import static me.freezehome.blog.factory.SqlFactory.*`to be able to compile, just told that because it is not in your snippet.

Comment: Sorry， it's my fault not paste all code. I have update code

Comment: I have tried your code, it is compiling fine. And there is no Integer from your error message ...

Comment: I am relly sorry for forgetting paste function

Comment: I understand better now, there is indeed a conflict between `String ToDoDAO.finished` and parameter `Integer finished`